# Hp 8570p Linux performance USB3

Tags: linux, usb, usb-3

When I plug in a USB 3.0 stick on the USB 3.0 ports on the right side of the device (confirmed by the manual) the speed is on around the level of USB 2.

Confirmed with another 8570p

KaOS Linux, with the latest drivers. Also (other) live distros perform similar bad, same counts for real installations on the stick.

Here is the dmesg output while coping a 1.9 GB ISO: pastebin.com/vPdpb4UF

The fun thing is that the coping progress jumps from zero to about 650mb within the first two seconds, then it slows immediately down to 6mb per second. I also tried it with a 1.1 GB ISO, with a similar experience. There it even goes down to some kb/sec some MB before finishing.

The stick is a 13fe:5500 Kingston.

Is this about the drivers? 
How much of an impact has the UEFI here?

Comment: USB sticks vary in performance, as widely as cars... There are USB sticks equivalent to a 1963 Volkswagon and others equivalent to a new Ferarri in performance... We would need more information, such as the exact make and model of drive, the output of dmesg when connecting and copying files to it, and how you are testing it's performance to give you anything near a realistic answer.

Comment: Here is the output while coping a 1.9 GB ISO: 
https://pastebin.com/vPdpb4UF

The stick is a 13fe:5500 Kingston

The fun thing is that the coping progress jumps from zero to about 650mb within the first two seconds, then it slows immediately down to 6mb per second. 

I also tried it with a 1.1 GB ISO, with a similar experience. There it even goes down to some kb/sec some MB before finishing. 

How much of an impact has the UEFI here? 

I have yet to find a USB 3.0 stick which is as slow as 2.0 ones.. 
I also tried it with 3 different one, all the same result. 

Thanks a lot